# Proof of $\det A= \det A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

A is a $\ n$ by$\ n$ matrix. First I separated the case "$\det A$ is zero" and "$\det A$ is not zero". And I considered the latter case, and now I know that $\det PA=\det A^TP^T$, because $\det PA=\det L\det D\det U$ by LDU decomposition (P is a permutation matrix), and $\det (PA)^T$ is equals to $\det U^T\det D^T\det L^T$. And both of them equal to $\det D$, so $\det PA=\det A^TP^T$. So, now I know that $\det P \det A=\det A^T \det P^T$, and I don't know how to prove that $\det P=\det P^T$. Can someone help me?

Comment: What is your definition of $\det A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$det(P)$ is given by $(-1)^t$ where $t$ is the number of row swaps you need to do in order to turn it into the identity matrix.

Similarly, $det(P^T) = (-1)^t$, where instead of swapping rows you swap columns.